# Differentiable function on interval has no removable discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function defined on the interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the function $f'$ can have no removable discontinuities.

Could someone help me on this one? I would like to use the "mean value theorem for derivatives":
"Let $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function defined on the interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Take $x_{1},x_{2} \in I$ with $x_{1}<x_{2}$ for which $f'(x_{1}) \neq f'(x_{2})$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that y lies strictly between $f'(x_{1})$ and $f'(x_{2})$. Then there exists a $x \in ]x_{1},x_{2}[$ for which $f'(x)=y$."

Comment: Sorry it was meant to say that $f'$ has no removable discontinuities.

Comment: If there is a removable discontinuity at $a$, then $f'(a)$ is either greater than or less than $f(a+)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now . You want to use the mean value theorem for f ;NOT f'. You should show that if f'(x) ---> A as x---> c (could be one sided limits also ) then the difference quotient f(x)-f(c) /x-c ---> A  which means f'(c)=A . This will be easy for  you ,I think ,because the difference quotient above is the value of the derivative at a point closer to c than x and for points sufficiently close  to c the value of  the derivative is as close as one would like to A .